# How to pass a var to a getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function editar(clicked_id){
 var currentID = clicked_id;
alert(clicked_id);
}
```

I want to pass the `var currentID` to the `getElementById`

```
var tituloAgain = document.getElementById(clicked_id).value;
console.log(tituloAgain);
```

Comment: How u calling editor function

Comment: Just pass your variable in .val()

Comment: You question should be included in the body of the post, not just in the title.

Comment: Please state your intent with the function

Answer (score 0):

You can move the definition of the currentID outside of the function to make it a global variable. Then you can assign it a value inside the function like this:

```
var currentID;
function editar(clicked_id){
    currentID = clicked_id;
    alert(clicked_id);
}
var tituloAgain = document.getElementById(currentID).value;
console.log(tituloAgain);
```